# Question about an example for a simply connected set

Tags: complex-analysis

Im reading about simply connected regions in my complex analysis books (so we're working here with the complex plane). The definition of the author is the following :

A region (open and connected set) $ D $ is simply connected for any $z_0 $ in $ \tilde{D} $ (The complement of D), and for any $ \varepsilon >0 $ there is a continuous curve $ \gamma(t) , 0\leq t < \infty $ such that

a)$ d\left(\gamma\left(t\right),\tilde{D}\right)<\varepsilon $ for  all $ t\geq 0 $

b) $ \gamma(0) = z_0 $

c) $ \underset{t\to\infty}{\lim}\gamma\left(t\right)=\infty  $

Now one of the examples is the infinite strip $ S=\left\{ z:-1<ImZ<1\right\}  $

My question is about the meaning of $ \underset{t\to\infty}{\lim}\gamma\left(t\right)=\infty  $. What does it mean for a complex function to strive to infinity? in this specific example, as I understand it, the complex numbers from the lower part of the plane can only strive to "$-\infty $".

What is the acceptable meaning for the third condition?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subset\Bbb R$ is not bounded above and if $\gamma\colon A\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is a function, we say that$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma(t)=\infty$$if$$\bigl(\forall M\in(0,\infty)\bigr)\bigl(\exists N\in(0,\infty)\bigr):t>N\implies\bigl|\gamma(t)\bigr|>M.$$
Furthermore, note that there is no concept of $-\infty$ in the complex plane.

Comment: I see. To make sure that I get the idea of the simply connected set, is it true that a circle in the complex plane is simply connected? (at first it may look like points inside the disk cannot be connected to $\infty $ without crossing the circle, but even if they do, I think the first condition still holds for any $\varepsilon>0 $. Is it true?

Comment: A circle is *not* simply connected. If $z_0$ is the center of the circle, there is no such $\gamma$, since it would have to go through the circle.

Comment: But even if it would go through the circle, the condition $ d\left(\gamma\left(t\right),\tilde{D}\right)<\varepsilon $ would not hold for any $\varepsilon)$ ? I mean the distance between the circle to its complement in $ \mathbb{C} $ is $0$

Comment: My mistake. Anyway, a circle is not an open set, and therefore that statement does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{t \to \infty} \gamma(t) = \infty$ means:

$$\forall L > 0\,\, \exists M>0\,\, \text{such that}\,\, \forall t > L,\, |\gamma(t)| > M $$

In other words, $\lim_{t \to \infty} |\gamma(t)| = \infty$, in the usual sense of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. All "directions to infinity" are considered equal in this definition.

If you are familiar with the concept of the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), you may be interested to learn that this definition is the same as "tending to the north pole" on that sphere.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb C$, there is only one infinity. The statement

$$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$$

means that for all $M\in\Bbb R$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|z-a|<\delta\implies |f(z)|>M$$
amd similarly, mutatis mutandis, for $\lim_\limits{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$.